# How do I stop the increasing animation speed in a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, animation, canvas, game-physics

i have made a simpel game but I have a problem. if you click the link below you will understand. If one of the shoots fired misses the blue ball the speed of everyhing increases.

See the [Demo](http://elevweb.akershus-fk.no/~stmo0403/it2/spill/) click the link
press ENTER to start

the code for the game is below

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var tileldig = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
var tekst = document.getElementById("tekst")

var kuler = [
    {r: 10, x: canvas.width/2, y: canvas.height-100, f: "red", dy:0},
]

var fiender = [
    {r: 20, x: tileldig, y: -20, vx:0 , vy: 1, },
]

var snd = new Audio("Skudd.m4a");

var poeng = 1;
var høyre = 0;
var venstre = 0;
var opp = 0;
var ned = 0;

document.onkeydown = function tast (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {  // høyre
            høyre = 1;  
        } 
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {  // venstre
            venstre = 1;  
        } 
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {  // opp 
            opp = 1; 
        } 
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {  // ned
            ned = 1;              
        } 
        if(e.keyCode == 32) {
            newskudd();
            snd.play();
            console.log("hit space")
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            spill();
        }

}
document.onkeyup = function tast2 (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {  // høyre
            høyre = 0;  
        } 
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {  // venstre
            venstre = 0;  
        } 
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {  // opp 
            opp = 0; 
        } 
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {  // ned
            ned = 0;              
        } 
}

function spill() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < kuler.length; i++) { 
        kuler[i].x += 0;
        kuler[i].y += kuler[i].dy;


        ctx.fillStyle = kuler[i].f;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(kuler[i].x, kuler[i].y, kuler[i].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        if (venstre == 1){
            kuler[0].x -= 4;
        }
        if (høyre == 1){
            kuler[0].x += 4;;
        }
        if (opp == 1){
            kuler[0].y -= 4;
        }
        if (ned == 1){
            kuler[0].y += 4;
        }


        if (kuler[0].x >= canvas.width-kuler[0].r) {
            kuler[0].x = canvas.width-kuler[0].r
        };
        if (kuler[0].x <= 0+kuler[0].r) {
            kuler[0].x = 0+kuler[0].r
        };
        if (kuler[0].y >= canvas.height-kuler[0].r) {
            kuler[0].y = canvas.height-kuler[0].r
        };
        if (kuler[0].y <= 0+kuler[0].r) {
            kuler[0].y = 0+kuler[0].r
        };



    for (var j = 0; j < fiender.length; j++) { 
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(fiender[j].x, fiender[j].y, fiender[j].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        fiender[j].y += fiender[j].vy;

        if (fiender[j].x >=  canvas.width -fiender[j].r) {
            fiender[j].x =canvas.width - fiender[j].r;
        };
        if (fiender[j].x  <= 0 + fiender[j].r) {
            fiender[j].x =0 + fiender[j].r;
        };  

        if (fiender[j].vy >= 2) {
            fiender[j].vy = 2;  
        };


        /*if (fiender[j].y + fiender[j].r >= kuler[i].y && fiender[j].x + fiender[j]. == kuler[i].x) { // remove kuler[i] and fiender[j] } 
            fiender.splice(j, 1);
            kuler.splice(i,1);
        };*/

        var distanceFromCenters = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(fiender[j].x - kuler[i].x),2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(fiender[j].y - kuler[i].y),2 )); // you have a collision
        if (distanceFromCenters <= (fiender[j].r + kuler[i].r)) {
            fiender.splice(j, 1);
            kuler.splice(i,1);
            poeng += 1;
        } else if (fiender[j].y > canvas.height) {
            fiender.splice(j,1)
        }

        if(j > 1){ 
            fiender.splice(j,1)

        }


        tekst.innerHTML = ( "Poeng: " + poeng  )
    }
}






    requestAnimationFrame(spill);
}

function newskudd () {
    var nyttskudd = 
    {x:kuler[0].x, y:kuler[0].y, r:5, dy:-5, f:"white"};
    kuler.push(nyttskudd);
};

setInterval(
    function(){
        fiender.push({r: 20, x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1), y: -20, vx:0 , vy: 1, f: "green"});
}, 1000);
```

Comment: your demo doesn't do anything.- Oh, it does when you run spill() in the console.

Comment: you have to press enter to start

Comment: You told us, that everything increases. But what exactly is your desired behaviour?

Comment: So you DO NOT want the speed to increase? Or what?

Comment: no i do not want the speed to increas when i press space

Comment: Also, can you please use english variables with english meanings?

Comment: witch varables dont you understand?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that you moved **player** and **enemies** in a `loop` that was processed for each bullet. Thus, the more bullets you had, the more times you increased **player** and **enemy** positions.

So: **your game speed doesn't increase.** You simply move player's and enemies' positions in a place in your code that is inside another loop.

This is what you had before (pseudo-code):

```
// INCORRECT!
for each bullet {
    move_bullet();
    move_player();
    for each enemy {
        move_enemy();
    }
}

// CORRECT:
for each bullet {
    move_bullet();
}
move player;
for each enemy {
    move_enemy()
}
```

The reason for this may be **poor code formatting.** You have wrong numbers of spaces for different blocks and *that* may be the reason why you got this problem. I've ran your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ to find the problem.

I've moved those under the main loop. You can see the old and new places, I've added comments.

Here's your panacea: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/mho43ek7/

Comment: when I use this code the collition between the red ball and the blue balls dont work

Comment: the collition dosent work in the panacea you provided. in the panacea the animation stops becaus there is an error, not because a collotion was detected